# Django subprocess erratic string error when rendering html page to pdf

Tags: python, django, subprocess, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using django for a very specific website, and I need to generate a pdf using the command line and `wkhtmltopdf`.

Most of the time it works great, but sometimes I get this error:

```
execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

Here is the faulty code :

```
# Get our HTML page as string
payload = show_pdf(request, as_pdf=True)
file_data = render_to_string('quotation/pdf.html', payload, RequestContext(request))

#First echo our HTML page's string and give it to wkhtmltopdf for smooth transformation to pdf

p1 = subprocess.Popen(['echo', file_data], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['wkhtmltopdf', '-q', '--zoom', zoom_factor, '--encoding', 'utf-8', '-', 'test.pdf'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

I suspected an encoding problem but my html page is already rendered as utf-8 and forcing encoding do not change anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: I still didn't found a solution but it seems to work on my local dev env but not on production server.

Comment: Ok it seems that I found the correct solution :  
  
`p1 = subprocess.Popen(['echo', str_smart(file_data)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`  
  
str_smart seems to be the trick here :)